# Jquery hover hide/show: setTimeout clearTimeout

Tags: jquery, hover, settimeout

So I have an element(link) that controls the visibility of another element(target) by hovering on it.
When the the mouse hovers the link the target is supposed to turn to visible and when the mouse leaves the target is supposed to turn invisible after 2 seconds.

So far so good. But how do I make it so that if the mouse goes hover the visible target before the 2 seconds go up, the target stays visible?

I got it to sort of work with setTimeout and clearTimeout but its really buggy and it doesn't feel good at all.

```
var time = 1000;
$(".link").hover(

      function () {
        $('.target').css('display', 'none');
        clearTimeout($(this).data('timeout'));
          $('.target').css({'display': 'block'});
      },

      function () { 

        var timer = setTimeout(function() {$('.target').fadeOut(1000).delay(100).css('display', 'none'); clearTimeout(timer); }, time);

        $('.target').hover(
              function () {
                clearTimeout(timer);
              },
              function () {
                var timer = setTimeout(function() {$('.target').fadeOut(1000).delay(100).css('display', 'none'); clearTimeout(timer); }, time);
              }
            );        
      }

); ​
```

(http://jsfiddle.net/VfDkq/)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try re-factoring your code a bit:

```
(function() {

    var time = 1000,
        timer;

    function handlerIn() {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        $('.target').stop(true).css('opacity', 1).show();
    }
    function handlerOut() {
        timer = setTimeout(function() {
            $('.target').fadeOut(3000);
        }, time);
    }

    $(".link, .target").hover(handlerIn, handlerOut);

}());
```

[**Live demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/VfDkq/6/)

This should be really close to your described behavior. I've also added an extra line to display it right back when you `mouseenter` while it's fading out, as you can see in the `handlerIn`.

---

A couple mistakes that I took away from your code:

- You had another `timer` var declared inside one of the `mouseleave` handlers, which couldn't be cancelled anywhere. The `timer` must be accessible in a common scope;
- You were applying animation delays before the synchronous method `.css`, which has no effect;
- There's no point to set the `display` to `none` after a [`fadeOut`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) has completed, it automatically does so;
- There's no point to clear a `setTimeout` after it has executed either.

Comment: It feels really close but the event that was creating the buggy behavior is still there. Forgot to mention it on the original post.

If you hover the link immediately after you leave, the timeout doesn't clear.

In other words. if you in and out really quickly from the link area, the target div still goes way and sometime it creates some erratic behavior.

Comment: Of course, I forgot to assign the `timer` var lol my bad. @PedroGonçalves Just updated my code & fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You are using too much delays and fadeout durations. Browsers do not like it. Do you mind using hide() instead of those?

http://jsfiddle.net/VfDkq/4/

```
  var timer = setTimeout(function() {$('.target').hide().css('display', 'none'); clearTimeout(timer); }
```

Or you can lessen delay time and fadeout duration.